# nginx proxy cache configuration for user authentication web application

Tags: nginx, proxy, cache, node.js, user-accounts

I have a web application in node + express + passport + mongo database + ejs and single application is configured to handle all the sub-domains. I'm using nginx as proxy server, I need to and must use proxy cache as to reduce load on node server.

I have 2 issues,

*1. I need to configure nginx proxy cache as it should make different cache for individual subdomain.*

*2. For logged in user content will change little bit. how can i manage this..?*

Please help me get it solved.

thanks in advance.

**following is the configuration**

```
upstream backend_app_hosts {
    server localhost:3005 max_fails=0 fail_timeout=10s;
    server localhost:3006 max_fails=0 fail_timeout=10s;    
    keepalive 64;
}
proxy_cache_path  /var/www/cache levels=1:2 keys_zone=cache-1:8m max_size=1000m inactive=600m;

server {
    listen 80 ;
        charset UTF-8;
        client_max_body_size 16M;
        keepalive_timeout 20;

        server_name  *.domain.com;    


        location / {
          proxy_redirect off;
          proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP            $remote_addr;
          proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
          proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
          proxy_set_header   Host                   $http_host;
          proxy_set_header   X-NginX-Proxy    true;
          proxy_set_header   Connection "";
          proxy_http_version 1.1;          
          proxy_pass         http://backend_app_hosts/;

          proxy_cache cache-1;
          proxy_cache_valid  200 302  1440m;
          proxy_cache_valid  404      1m;

        }
}
```

Comment: You need to set `proxy_cache_key`.

Comment: what would be the value for     proxy_cache_key in my case..?

Comment: Start by reading its documentation.